# Output base-10 fixed point number in C

Tags: c, printf, fixed-point

I have an integer `n` representing a number multiplied by `1e<exp>` for some constant `<exp>`. For example, for an input number of `12.345` and an `<exp>` of 4, `n = 123450`. I want to output the original number, with no trailing zeros, as fast as possible.

Some potential (but flawed) solutions:

```c
// Pros:
//  - Very simple
//  - Does not output trailing zeros
// Cons:
//  - Converts to float (slow, inaccurate)
printf("%g", n * 1e-<exp>);
```

```c
// Pros:
//  - Quite simple
//  - Uses only integer arithmetic
// Cons:
//  - Outputs trailing zeros
printf("%d.%.0<exp>d", n / (int)1e<exp>, n % (int)1e<exp>);
```

Comment: Let’s call <exp> e. What is the range of e? Could it be such that n•10^−e is less than 1? Less than .1? Could it be negative? What is the range of n? Could it be negative? Could it be zero? If e is a constant, would you want different code for each possible value of it, if that would improve time? If the number is 100, do you want “100.”, “100”, or “1” (no trailing zeros)?

Comment: @EricPostpischil In this specific case, n will be positive and >=1, however a more general solution would be ideal. The solution would ideally be easily modifiable to different values of e, but not at the cost of speed. If the number is 100, the output should be either "100" or "100.0", though "100." would be acceptable if it provides a noticeable speed increase

Comment: Please answer all questions. There is a reason for asking whether n^−e could be less than .1. If it cannot, we can convert n to a string, print some of its digits, print a decimal point, and print more of its digits, up to where trailing zeros start. If it can, we need to print a decimal point first and then some zeros, and that requires calculating how big n is (which might happen in the conversion to string anyway, but it could mean not calling a library routine to do that). So again, can e be such that 10^−e is less than .1? What is the range of n? Can it be negative?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Sorry, I accidentally wrote n in my previous comment. n*10^-e will be positive and >=1. The upper bound of n is 2^64-1

Comment: A third possibility is to extract the digits yourself, and output them with `putchar`. The combination of *"as fast as possible"* and *"printf"* is an oxymoron.

Comment: @user3386109, good point, `printf` is not ideal. A fast solution using `putchar` or `puts` would be great :)

Comment: So, there is essentially no escaping the fact that n must be converted to decimal. Then it is simply a matter of using e to position the decimal point. One might contemplate some improvements, such as omitting trailing zeros in the conversion of n based on knowledge of e, but I am skeptical there is much to gain there.

Answer (score 2):

Your first naive solution does not work for values of `<exp>` greater than 6. Here is a simple function. You can adjust the integer type and `printf` format accordingly:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int print_fixed(int n, int exp, FILE *fp) {
    char buf[32];
    int len = snprintf(buf + 1, sizeof(buf) - 1, "%.*d", exp + 1, n);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len - exp; i++) {
        buf[i] = buf[i + 1];
    }
    buf[i] = '.';
    while (buf[len] == '0') {
        buf[len--] = '\0';
    }
    if (buf[len] == '.')
        buf[len--] = '\0';
    fputs(buf, fp);
    return len + 1;
}

int main() {
    int tests[][2] = {
        { 0, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 10, 1 }, { 100, 2 }, { 1000, 3 }, { 10000, 4 },
        { 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 1, 3 }, { 1, 4 },
        { 1, 0 }, { 12, 1 }, { 123, 2 }, { 1234, 3 }, { 12345, 4 },
        { 1, 0 }, { 12, 1 }, { 120, 2 }, { 1204, 3 }, { 12040, 4 },
        { -1, 0 }, { -12, 1 }, { -120, 2 }, { -1204, 3 }, { -12040, 4 },
    };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(tests) / sizeof(tests[0]); i++) {
        printf("print_fixed(%d, %d, stdout) -> ", tests[i][0], tests[i][1]);
        print_fixed(tests[i][0], tests[i][1], stdout);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am always motivate to vote down answers that are all code with no documentation or explanation. Stack Overflow is not supposed to be a write-my-code service; it is supposed to answer questions and inform people.

Comment: The manipulations of the buffer can be replaced by using `fwrite` to write the initial digits, `fputc` to write the decimal point, and `fwrite` to write the trailing digits, and this could be faster.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I considered this alternative but 3 separate calls to the C library might actually be slower due to stream locking. It would probably be more efficient to construct the string with divisions instead of relying on `snprintf` as in 4386427's answer but it is easier to adapt the above code to the type of integer the OP uses.

Comment: Yes, stream locking is a good point. I doubt self-conversion with divisions will perform well; the library routines should be optimized for binary-to-decimal conversion. Since e is a constant, an improvement might be possible by converting (`snprintf`) n/T, “.”, and n%T (where T is the constant 10^e) and truncating trailing zeros.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this will perform but you can try it out and let us know.

```
#define BUF_SZ 32

void p(unsigned n, unsigned exp)
{
    char br[BUF_SZ];
    int ix = BUF_SZ - 1;
    br[ix--] = '\0';
    while(exp)
    {
        // Skip trailing zeros
        int t = n % 10;
        n = n / 10;
        exp--;
        if (t)
        {
            br[ix--] = '0' + t;
            break;
        }
    }

    while(exp)
    {
        br[ix--] = '0' + n % 10;
        n = n / 10;
        exp--;
    }

    // Only insert a '.' if something has been printed
    if (ix != (BUF_SZ - 2)) br[ix--] = '.';

    do
    {
        br[ix--] = '0' + n % 10;
        n = n / 10;
    } while(n);

    puts(&br[ix + 1]);
}
```

It prints no trailing zero and no '.' when there is no decimals.

Performance unknown.