# Truncate Numbers in C

Tags: c

The whole point of this exercise was to not use floating points.

I have an unsigned long number, say 123456; it represents 123.456. I want to convert this number using sprintf() function so I can output it via UART but with a decimal point

Currently I have have 2 variables, number_integer and number_decimal, to capture the integers I have:

number_integer = 123456 / 1000;

my question is, how do I assigned number_decimal to the last 3 numbers of the original, i.e. 456?

I think that I need to bitwise & the original number like:

number_decimal = 123456 & 0x07;

but this returns the wrong value.

Comment: `123456 % 1000` gives you `456`

Comment: Since computers generally use base 2 and you are looking at/thinking of the number in base 10, bitwise won't do what you want it to do. That would have worked if you were dealing only with base 2 across the board.

Comment: Masking work 0x07 will zero the least significant _binary_ digits.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Output base-10 fixed point number in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63677636/output-base-10-fixed-point-number-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

It is quite simple - you also need a remainder which goes after the dot using the modulo operator `%`:

```
void printScaled(int number)
{
    printf("%s%d.%03d\n", number < 0 ? "-" : "", abs(number / 1000), abs(number % 1000));
}


int main(void)
{
    printScaled(12345678);
    printScaled(-1);
    printScaled(1);
    printScaled(0);
    printScaled(-34535353);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qqdzYq5Ea

Comment: This fails for input `-1` which outputs `0.001`. I suggest your `printScaled()` should work with the absolute value, after printing a `-` if needed, such as `if(number < 0) printf("-"); int val = abs(number); printf("%d.%03d\n", val / 1000, val % 1000);`.

Comment: @WeatherVane good spot, but `abs(number)` may invoke undefined behaviour for `INT_MIN`

Comment: Testing the sign is over-complicated. You can just output `number / 1000` and get the sign for free: https://godbolt.org/z/ssds9evsP ... On a separate note, be aware that not all locales use `.` as the decimal separator character.

Comment: @paddy it does not work for number < 1000 as two compilent standard does not have the negative zero. I have changed the code from the one you showed to avoid this error.  Check edits. Do not criticise **before testing** your ideas

Comment: Fair call! Need more coffee to boot up the brain this morning. :)

Comment: gulpr, "the modulo operator %:" is a slight misnomer. IMO, better as the [remainder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638659/2410359) operator.

Comment: @paddy you were in fact correct.  The question is specific that the value is unsigned, so there is no need to deal with the sign at all.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an unsigned long number, say 123456; it represents 123.456. I want to convert this number using sprintf() function so I can output it via UART but with a decimal point

As OP has an *unsigned long number*, sufficient to break the number into a whole number and a fraction part with a `/1000` and `%1000` and control minimum print widths with `"03"`.
Use a buffered sized to *fix point* and [`unsigned long`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31542396/2410359) needs.

```
// Buffer size needed about the bit-width * log2(10) plus a few extra.
#define UL_FP3_SZ (sizeof(unsigned long)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 3)
char [UL_FP3_SZ];
unsigned long number = ...;

sprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%lu.%03lu\n", number / 1000u, number % 1000u);
output_via_UART(buf);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a decimal fixed-point unsigned value with three decimal places (which is what you have described):

```
unsigned long int_part = fixed_value / 1000u ;
unsigned fract_part = fixed_value % 1000u ;
```

Simple decimal arithmetic.

Your bitwise attempt would apply if you were using *binary* fixed-point, but a fractional part of just three *binary* digits would give increments of 1/8 (0.125).

Comment: It will not work for `-1000 < fixed_value < 0`

Comment: @gulpr agreed, corrected; the question explicitly stated `unsigned long` so the problem goes away with the correct type.